# Android Root Files after Unroot?

Tags: android

I rooted my phone and unrooted it. However several apps show me that i have a rooted phone. The warranty bit is 0x0 and the flash counter also.
Could there be any files which were not deleted?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to [android stackexchange](http://android.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Agree on the comment about this question being off-topic, but on the development part of it, root detection is done by heuristics detecting specific files commonly used for this purpose and not present in stock Android versions. So, in your case, that's probably what's happening.

For example, you can read this article for an overview of such techniques: https://blog.netspi.com/android-root-detection-techniques/